# React js Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make a socket connection to my backend through my front end, but sme successfully

I declared my socket in my state and then opened the connection, but I don't know why this error:

code:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props, context){
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {
      queue: '',
      socket: null
  };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    // io() not io.connect()
    this.state.socket = io('http://localhost:9000');

    this.state.socket.on('queue', (queue) => {
      this.setState({
        queue
      })
    });

    this.state.socket.open();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.state.socket.close();
  }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
               <p> Queue: {this.state.queue}  </p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: <p> Queue: {this.state.queue}  </p> What sytnax is this? Is Queue meant to be a string or is that an object?

Comment: Could you provide the Error you get. Queue is a string

Comment: queue is an object, i change my stete to:    this.state = {
      queue: {},
  };

Comment: and same rror :(

Comment: If queue is a object, you can't render it directly. You can render it's keys and/or values as strings.. do you _want_ to render a object for users to see?

Comment: Simm, as I could show this object, in console.log I can use queue.players

Answer (score 1):

You should not set the state directly by using `this.state.socket = ...`

Instead of setting `socket` as a state, you can try using `this.socket`.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props, context){
    super(props, context);
    this.socket = null;
    this.state = {
      queue: '',
  };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    // io() not io.connect()
    this.socket = io('http://localhost:9000');

    this.socket.on('queue', (queue) => {
      this.setState({
        queue: queue
      })
    });

    this.socket.open();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.socket.close();
  }

  render() {
      return (
          <div>
             <p> Queue: {this.state.queue}  </p>
          </div>
      )
  }
}
```

Comment: ×
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in p (at App.js:33)
    in div (at App.js:32)
    in App (at src/index.js:5)

Comment: ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

Comment: @gabriel sorry for my late response, I am unsure what `this.state.queue`'s type is, can you do a little debug, `console.log(queue)` in your event listening?

Comment: @gabriel if `queue` is an object, you have to convert it into an array. You can use something like `Object.keys(queue).map(key => queue[key])`

Comment: is a object thansk bro.

Answer (score 0):

Don't set a state object directly. Set it with setState({}).

```
  componentDidMount() {
    // io() not io.connect()
    const socket = io('http://localhost:9000');

    socket.on('queue', (queue) => {
      this.setState({
        queue,
      });
    });
    socket.open();

    this.setState({ socket });
  }
```